# Swift: Populate TableView with data that has a specific value in a JSON file

Tags: json, swift, uitableview

I know how to populate a table view with data from a JSON based on a specific key, but I am trying to figure out how to only put the data into the table view if it has a specific value in the key-value pair.

Specifically, my JSON file holds a key-value pair that is:
"location": "Chicago, IL", 
"continent": "US"

I want my table view to display the location of any entry that has the continent value of "US" and I do not want it to display any locations that have a different continent associated with them.

Any help I can get would be appreciated. Here is what I have in my parseJSON file but it currently does not work to do what I want to do. I get an Array index out of range in the tableview function

```
    func parseJSON(){
    do{
        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "https://jsonblob.com/api/jsonBlob/580d0ccce4b0bcac9f837fbe")!)

        let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)

        for anItem in jsonResult as! [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]{

            let mifiContinent = anItem["continent"] as! String!
            if var mifiContinent = jsonResult["US"]{
                let mifiLocation = anItem["location"] as! String
                let newLocation = Location(location: mifiLocation)
                locationOfMifi.append(newLocation)
            }
        }
    }
    catch let error as NSError{
        print(error.debugDescription)
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("LocationCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)as? LocationCell{

        let location: Location!

        location = locationOfMifi[indexPath.row]
        cell.configureCell(location)
        return cell

    } else{
        return UITableViewCell()
    }

}
```

Comment: You're likely getting the out of range error because your `locationOfMifi`array that you're using in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` has somehow been misaligned with your tables data source.  Can you show your `numberOfRowsInSection` method as well?

Comment: Ok this sounds like the perfect job for CoreData. You have to create a data model that would have all the corresponding attributes to your points of interest. In your case that would be the continent. Then you could tell CoreData to fetch you anything that has North America as its continent. Using CoreData instead of just an Array will do wonders for your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change a bit on your filtering

```
let mifiContinent = anItem["continent"] as! String!
if mifiContinent == "US" {
   let mifiLocation = anItem["location"] as! String
   let newLocation = Location(location: mifiLocation)
   locationOfMifi.append(newLocation)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try some swift-ish syntax to help out with what you're doing.  You'll have to modify configuring your cell just slightly.

```
struct Location {
    var location: String?
    var continent: String?

    init(_ jsonResult: [String : AnyObject]) {
      self.location = jsonResult["location"] as? String
      self.continent = jsonResult["continent"] as? String
    }
}

//defined in your class
var locationOfMifi = [Location]()

//where parsing your json result
if let jsonResult = jsonResult as? [[String : AnyObject]] {
    locationOfMifi = jsonResult.map({ Location($0) }).filter({ $0.continent == "US" })
}

//your tableview datasource
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return locationOfMifi.count
}
```